# What is the most efficient way to clear row if ALL cells have a value with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to come up with a function that will clear contents (not delete row) if all cells in a range have values. The script below isn't functioning as expected, and I would really appreciate any help/advice you all have. It's currently only clearing out a single line, and doesn't appear to be iterating over the whole dataset. My thought was to iterate over the rows, and check each cell individually. If each of the variables has a value, clear that range and go to the next row.

Here's a [link to a sample Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bcrEZo3IkXiKeyD47C_k2LIRy9N9M6SI2h2MGK1Cj-w/edit?usp=sharing), with data and the script in Script Editor.

```
function MassRDDChange() {
       // Google Sheet Record Details
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bcrEZo3IkXiKeyD47C_k2LIRy9N9M6SI2h2MGK1Cj-w');
       var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry');

       // Initial Sheet Values
       var newLastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
       var newLastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
       var dataToProcess = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, newLastRow, newLastColumn).getValues().filter(function(row) {
           return row[0]
       }).sort();
       var dLen = dataToProcess.length;

       // Clear intiial sheet
       for (var i = 0; i < dLen; ++i) {
           var row = 2;
           var orderNumber = dataToProcess[i][0].toString();
           var rdd = dataToProcess[i][1].toString();
           var submittedBy = dataToProcess[i][2].toString();
           var submittedOn = dataToProcess[i][3].toString();
           if (orderNumber && rdd && submittedBy && submittedOn) {
               dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, newLastColumn).clear();
               row++;
           } else {
               row++; // Go to the next row
               continue;
           }
       }
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks,  I'-'I. Sorry for leaving that part out. I've added more information about the Google Sheet, along with the script I have in Script Editor. In the example, I would want to clear any rows >= 2 where all 4 cells in the row have values in them.

Comment: You can use Logger.log() or the debugger to step through the code and see what it is actually doing.  If you aren't sure what the code is doing, you need a way to know exactly what it's doing.  [Link to troubleshooting guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: You are setting `row` to 2 on every loop.  `var row = 2;`  Move that outside of the loop.

Comment: Perfection. Please feel free to add as the answer, and I'll mark as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to delete the rows, just `clear()` them, and they're all on the same worksheet tab, this is a great use case for [`RangeList`s](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list), which allow you to apply specific `Range` methods to non-contiguous `Range`s. Currently, the only way to [create a `RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeList(String)) is from a an array of reference notations (i.e. a `RangeList` is different than an [array of `Range` objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#getRanges())), so the first goal we have is to prefix our JavaScript array of sheet data to inspect with a usable reference string. We could write a function to convert array indices from 0-base integers to A1 notation, but R1C1 referencing is perfectly valid to pass to the `RangeList` constructor, so we just need to account for header rows and the 0-base vs 1-base indexing difference.

The strategy, then, is to:

1. Batch-read sheet data into a JavaScript `Array`
2. Label each element of the array (i.e. each row) with an R1C1 string that identifies the location where this element came from.
3. `Filter` the sheet data array based on the contents of each element

   - Keep elements where each sub-element (the column values in that row) converts to a boolean (i.e., does not have the same value as an empty cell)
4. Feed the labels of each of the kept rows to the [`RangeList` constructor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeList(String))
5. Use `RangeList` methods on the `RangeList`

Because this approach uses only 3 Spreadsheet calls (besides the initial setup for a batch read), vs 1 per row to clear, it should be considerably faster.

```
function clearFullyFilledRows() {
  // Helper function that counts the number of populated elements of the input array.
  function _countValues(row) {
    return row.reduce(function (acc, val) {
      var hasValue = !!(val || val === false || val === 0); // Coerce to boolean
      return acc + hasValue; // true == 1, false == 0
    }, 0);
  }
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const numHeaderRows = 1,
      numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - numHeaderRows;
  const startCol = 1,
      numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();

  // Read all non-header sheet values into a JavaScript array.
  const values = sheet.getSheetValues(1 + numHeaderRows, startCol, numRows, numCols);

  // From these values, return a new array where each row is the origin
  // label and the count of elements in the original row with values.
  const labeledCounts = values.map(function(row, index) {
    var rNc = "R" + (numHeaderRows + 1 + index) + "C";
    return [
      rNc + startCol + ":" + rNc + (startCol + numCols - 1),
      _countValues(row)
    ];
  });

  // Filter out any row that is missing a value.
  const toClear = labeledCounts.filter(function (row) { return row[1] === numCols; });

  // Create a RangeList from the first index of each row (the R1C1 label):
  const rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(toClear.map(function (row) { return row[0]; }));
  // Clear them all:
  rangeList.clear();
}
```

Note that because these cleared rows are possibly disjoint, your resulting sheet may be littered with rows having data, and rows not having data. A call to `sheet.sort(1)` would sort all the non-frozen rows in the sheet, moving the newly-empty rows to the bottom (yes, you can programmatically set frozen rows). Depending how this sheet is referenced elsewhere, that may not be desirable though.

Additional references:

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Syntax)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax)
- [JavaScript Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)
- [JavaScript Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: Thanks for that information, @tehhowch. I didn't even know that was a solution. Your code worked perfectly, and did exactly what I was expecting! Solution marked as answer.